# String matching in R using stringdist and dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to match two columns of drug names in a dataframe using the `stringdist` function and I'm not able to get my desired result.

I have a data frame where I have the original drug names that someone has provided and then I have a column containing the official drug names and their corresponding codes.

```
df <- data.frame(orig_names = c("KOGENATE", "KOGENATE", "ADVATE", "ADVATE"),
                 desired_names = c("KOGENATE FS", "ADVATE", "ADVATE", "RECOMBINATE"),
                 desired_names_code = c(1,2,3,4))
```

I wish to retain only those columns with the best match such that it results in the following data frame

```
desired_df <- data.frame(orig_names = c("KOGENATE", "ADVATE"),
                         desired_names = c("KOGENATE FS", "ADVATE"),
                         desired_names_code = c(1,3))
```

I've tried using various methods in the stringdist package as well as altering the distance metric but the results vary wildly.

```
library(stringdist)

result <- df %>% 
  filter(stringdist::stringdist(orig_names,desired_names, method = "jw") > 0.5)
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What defines a "best match"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're right with the fuzzy matching approach. Using `fuzzyjoin` package here allows you to join the (separated) orig_names and desired_names then find the closest match for each of the desired_names. It's a bit of a weird output because you have two 'ADVATE's in your desired_names but still, I think this is the cleanest solution.

```
library(fuzzyjoin)

df1 <- df %>% select(orig_names)
df2 <- df %>% select(-orig_names)

stringdist_join(df1, df2,
                by = c('orig_names' = 'desired_names'),
                mode = 'right',
                method = 'jw',
                max_dist = 99,
                distance_col = 'dist') %>% 
  group_by(desired_names) %>% 
  slice_min(order_by = dist, n = 1) %>% 
  distinct()

# A tibble: 4 x 4
# Groups:   desired_names [3]
  orig_names desired_names desired_names_code   dist
  <fct>      <fct>                      <dbl>  <dbl>
1 ADVATE     ADVATE                         2 0     
2 ADVATE     ADVATE                         3 0     
3 KOGENATE   KOGENATE FS                    1 0.0909
4 KOGENATE   RECOMBINATE                    4 0.290
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to achieve my desired result using `str_detect` from `{stringr}`

```
result <- df %>% 
  filter(stringr::str_detect(desired_names, pattern = orig_names)
```

Comment: Nice! Though because it won't do any fuzzy matching, this solution would not work if there were spelling errors or similar problems with orig_names, depends on your dataset :)